# Can't compare cell values with a single string

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets and I'm comparing a cell value with a string.

```
            lastRowSheet2 = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lastRowSheet1 = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

                    For Each c In Sheet2.Range("C2:C" & lastRowSheet2)
                    If (c.Value = "Solicitud") Then
                        Sheet1.Range("A" & lastRowSheet1 + 1 & ":A" & lastRowSheet1 + lastRowSheet2 - 1).Value = "Request / Headcount"
                    Else
                        Sheet1.Range("A" & lastRowSheet1 + 1 & ":A" & lastRowSheet1 + lastRowSheet2 - 1).Value = "Incidents / Headcount"
                    End If
                Next c
```

The problem is that the If condition is not working, only puts the value of Else condition, It does not make a distinction of the cell value and the string that I am comparing. What I'm doing wrong?

In advance thank you very much

Comment: That is because you are inputing the value into the whole range each loop and it will always then be the value of the last condition in the loop.  do `Sheet1.Range("A" & lastRowSheet1 + c.row - 1).Value = ...`

Comment: It works!, Thank you @ScottCraner